# How to create a user 'programmatically' with Flask-user extension?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this extension used in my project: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/index.html

I also have a REST API and a *register()* function there which accepts JSON-object and should be able to create a new user.

How can I achieve this with ***Flask-user API***?

**UPDATE:**
I have a fully created User model. Basically I need some kind of User() constructor provided from Flask-user where I can pass the input from JSON-object.

*Why do I need it:*
Flask-user extension has its own way of working. For example, it sends e-mails to confirm an account, hashes password in its own way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it basically works:

```
user = User()
user.username = request.json['username']
user.first_name = request.json['first_name']
user.last_name = request.json['last_name']
user.email = request.json['email']
user.password = user_manager.hash_password(request.json['password'])

db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no, there is no built-in way to perform the registration the same way that Flask-User's [`register`](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/bb270155db5e9b15a5f4ad3afd207ce016a95e44/flask_user/views.py#L316) view does.  You'll have to do [everything that view does when handling a POST request](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/bb270155db5e9b15a5f4ad3afd207ce016a95e44/flask_user/views.py#L349-L460).  The basics are:

- Create and populate the models with the data you have.
- Use [`user_manager.hash_password(secret)`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/recipes.html#hashing-passwords) to create a hashed password, and set this on the user.
- Call [`_send_registered_email(user, email, True)`](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/bb270155db5e9b15a5f4ad3afd207ce016a95e44/flask_user/views.py#L657) to send the confirmation email.